# wxpython does not have 'adv'

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

TLDR first:
When using "`wx.adv.DatePickerCtrl(self)`", get "`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'adv'`"

longer story:
Just learning wxPython, trying to write a date picker using **DatePickerCtrl**.
Found example with '`wx.DatePickerCtrl`'. apparently it is only valid for version 2.8 (which I could not find anywhere).
Quick search shows it been replaced by `wx.adv.DatePickerCtrl(self)` in version 3. Now get the above massage (`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'adv'`)

(system: windows 10, python 2.7.10 32bit, wx 3.0.2.0 msw)

Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Classic versions of wxPython still have `wx.DatePicker`. It was only moved in Phoenix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

adv is an update with wxpython phoenix project which is basically a move to make wx python compatible with python 3+. For python 2.7, you can just use wx.DatePickerCtrl

https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/classic_vs_phoenix.html#classic-vs-phoenix

Answer (score 3):

`wx.DatePickerCtrl` is not included with the current download of wxPython.  Just add an `import wx.adv` and you will be fine.